# Day and month name translation in Drupal8

Tags: drupal-8

I am new to Drupal world and **creating a site in Urdu language in Drupal 8**. I have enabled its multilingual support and set default language to Urdu (in fact, this is the only language of the site).

I have created a content type and **enabled to show `Display author and date information`**. I have also added some contents for this content type. When I go to view some content, its **author and date information is displayed as below**.

`Submitted by mabilalmirza on Fri, 02/09/2018 - 23:33`

I know I can translate the string using translation interface but **I want the day name to be shown in Urdu, for example, `Fri` should be translated to `جمعہ`**. I want to translate month names as well for long date format.

Can anyone guide me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

go to your date format for example /admin/config/regional/date-time/formats/manage/long
and change lang to your or create new date format.

Comment: This only does configuration translation of a date format. I want to get actual date translated.

Answer (score 0):

Try "User interface translation" in Config (/admin/config/regional/translate). If you add translations to Urdu it should change "days" for you.